# Cannot load entity: "class" was not found in the chain configured

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, php-7

I'm new to Doctrine ORM and I have some problems retrieving an entity.

I get the following error when i try to retrieve my entity:

`'AppBundle\Entity\FeedImport' was not found in the chain configured namespaces`

I've used the Symfony CLI utilities `mapping:import` to generate my entity yaml files and `generate:entities` for creating the models.

I've searched for this error and most of the time it is all about custom bundles not being mapped correctly. But because I used the default bundle I don't know what should be wrong. Do I need to configure doctrine with more information?

Things I've checked:

`- AppBundle is active.
- AppBundle is registered.
- DefaultController of the AppBundle is loaded correctly.
- class FeedImport exists.
- class FeedImport has correct namespace.
- Tried switching naming strategy for doctrine. (It uses underscore namesping strategy by default, but my classes are in CamelCase)`

Can you see what is wrong? Any advise would be appreciated. Below is my configuration/setup details.

DefaultController.php

 `public function indexAction(Request $request)
 {
...........
        $feedImport = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(FeedImport::class)->find(1);
...........
}`

namespace of the FeedImport.php class:

`namespace AppBundle\Entity`

config.yml

`doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'
        mapping_types:
            enum: string
            set: string
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true`

App Module structure:

`AppBundle
    ├── AppBundle.php
    ├── Controller
    │   └── DefaultController.php
    ├── Entity
    │   ├── FeedImport.php
    ├── Repository
    │   └── FeedImportRepository.php
    └── Resources
        └── config
            └── doctrine
                ├── FeedImport.orm.yml`

Comment: Did you try clearing your cache and doctrine cache?

Comment: Yes I did, It didn't help

Comment: Found the solution, posted it in this thread: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571637/doctrine-cannot-map-entity-repository-namespace-in-chain/46716093#46716093